# Adding custom right click menu for specific extention for win7pro64 doesn't work

Tags: windows-registry

I have the a little problem developing right click context menu for ".prt" files. I did everything according to the recommendations, and I got a very strange result - the menu doesn't appear. If I deal with different file extension everything will going great, menu will appear, but the menu for `*.prt` doesn't work. What may be so specific about *.prt files?
There is reg-file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\prt_auto_file]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\prt_auto_file\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\prt_auto_file\shell\Convertto]
@="Convert to"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\prt_auto_file\shell\Convertto\command]
@=...

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\prt_auto_file\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\prt_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@=...
```

Comment: Is the prt file extension in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Comment: You may have to [associate the prt extension manually](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl) if it is not there

Comment: BTW,  a solution from Danijel Malik working great. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` globally rather than using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` which is limited to current user.
And seems you forgot to include `.prt` extension in defined handler:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.prt]
@="prt_auto_file"
```

Try a new code with something like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.prt]
@="prt_auto_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prt_auto_file]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prt_auto_file\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prt_auto_file\shell\Convertto]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prt_auto_file\shell\Convertto\command]
@="address\\to\\convertor\\application.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prt_auto_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prt_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="address\\to\\default\\application.exe"
```